# Flot Chart plot points with dynamic PHP variables

Tags: javascript, php, flot, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a table that is displaying numbers via laravel php.  The numbers are based on a one week time period and the values associated with each day update accordingly upon refresh. Now I need to get this data inside of a flot chart.  A typical flot chart will have static points like this:

```
var data = [[0, 0], [1, 10], [2,5], [3, 12], [4, 9], [5, 4], [6, 2]];
```

But I need each point to be dynamic like this:

```
@foreach($days as $day)
 var data = [[{{ $day['carbon']->format('F j, Y') }},{{ $day['total'] }}]]
@endforeach
```

And of course this breaks the chart and it doesn't work.  I am kinda stuck here.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First build the full array in PHP. Don't worry about javascript yet.

Something like this:

```
$data = [];
foreach($days AS $day) {
    $data[] = [$day['carbon']->format('F j, Y'), $day['total']];
}
```

Ideally, do this in your controller. Not in the view.

Now, in your view it becomes easy:

```
<script>
var data = {!! json_encode($data) !!};
```

Note the different `{!!` tag, that tells Laravel not to escape the output.

Comment: Well it definitely helped..at least i got the chart to show up but there are still no points plotted on the chart yet.  This is definitely a step in the right direction.  Thank you so much.